# using Nmap with proxychains4

Tags: nmap, scanning, kali-linux

i was trying to scan ports with Nmap trough proxychains4 in order to be anonymous while scanning , but after i used wireshark to capture to traffics , i saw that my private IP  didn't change and still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You capture traffic on your local machine so it should have your IP address as a source. Traffic should go from your IP to the proxy server, then from the proxy server to the target (it's where the IP address is changed). The problem exists only if the traffic goes directly to the target.

A part of the Nmap functionality is unavailable with proxychains. Here's a good link about it: https://www.1337pwn.com/using-nmap-with-proxychains-in-kali-linux/.

Also, some of the Nmap scan types are "aggressive" so it means you should have *permission from the target*. To better understand how Nmap works and have legal hands-on experience, use hacking platforms like *TryHackMe*, *HackTheBox*, or similar.

Comment: yes that's correct , i captured traffic on my local machine ,  shoud i run the wireshark in the target machine to see if my Ip has been change or no ?

Comment: @bryan yes, just check the source of packets on your target machine.

Comment: thank you brother for your answer , have a good day .